# Antd Resizable table columns in TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, antd

I'm implementing `antd` `<Table>` component and need to make columns resizable with `react-resizable`.
I was following the example in the [documentation](https://ant.design/components/table/#components-table-demo-resizable-column), but since my project in in TypeScript and using functional components I had to refactor it and I've faced issues with typings.
When I'm trying to implement that `onHeaderCell` from example:

```
const initialColumns: ColumnProps<Row>[] = myData.columns.map((column, index) => {
  return {
    ...
    onHeaderCell: (c: ColumnType<Row>) => ({
          width: c.width,
          onResize: handleResize(index),
        }),
    ...
  })
```

I'm getting this error:

> ...
> The types returned by 'onHeaderCell(...)' are incompatible between these types.
> Type '{ width: string | number | undefined; onResize: (e: SyntheticEvent<Element, Event>, resizeData: ResizeCallbackData) => void; }' has no properties in common with type 'HTMLAttributes'.

My `handleResize` looks like this:

```
const handleResize = (index: number) => (e: React.SyntheticEvent<Element, Event>, resizeData: ResizeCallbackData) => {
    const { size } = resizeData
    updateColumns((cols) => {
      const nextColumns = [...cols]
      nextColumns[index] = {
        ...nextColumns[index],
        width: size.width,
      }
      return nextColumns
    })
  }
```

I've moved `ResizableTitle` into separate component and `<Table />` is implemented this way

```
const components = {
    header: {
      cell: ResizableTitle,
    },
  }

  return (
    <Table
      bordered
      components={components}
      columns={columns} // columns come from the useState<ColumnProps<Row>[]>()
      ...
    />
  )
```

How can I change this to get desired results?

Comment: Have you found a solution? I'm seeing this same issue...

Comment: @clint_milner Yeah, I've found a solution. I got rid of `react-resizable` (which started working but resized for 1px only) and moved to custom event listener that acts pretty much like `Resizable` but works fine.

Comment: @clint_milner I can post parts of my code (without `react-resizable`) as an answer to that question if you need it

Comment: that would be great - thank you

Comment: @clint_milner No problem, check that out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I found a solution without using `react-resizable`

```
const [resizingColumnIndex, _setResizingColumnIndex] = useState<number>();
const resizingColumnIndexRef = useRef(resizingColumnIndex);
  
const setResizingColumnIndex = (index: number | undefined) => {
    resizingColumnIndexRef.current = index;
    _setResizingColumnIndex(index);
};

const resizeListener = (e: MouseEvent) => {
  if (resizingColumnIndexRef.current) {
    handleResize(resizingColumnIndexRef.current, e.movementX);
  }
  window.onmouseup = (e: MouseEvent) => {
    window.removeEventListener("mousemove", resizeListener);
    setResizingColumnIndex(undefined);
  };
};
```

In each column title I'm adding

```
<div
  className="resizeHandle"
  onMouseDown={() => {
    setResizingColumnIndex(index);
    window.addEventListener("mousemove", resizeListener, { passive: true });
  }}
/>
```

having style of

```
  .resizeHandle {
    position: absolute;
    width: 10px;
    height: 100%;
    bottom: 0;
    right: -5px;
    cursor: col-resize;
    z-index: 5;
  }
```

Finally the `handleResize` function that updates columns kept in state of the component

```
  const handleResize = (index: number, delta: number) => {
    updateColumns(prevColumns => {
      const indexNewWidth = Number(prevColumns[index].width) + delta;
      const nextWidth = indexNewWidth >= MIN_COLUMN_WIDTH ? indexNewWidth : MIN_COLUMN_WIDTH;
      return prevColumns.map((col, i) => (i === index ? { ...col, width: nextWidth } : col));
    });
    setTableWidth(prevWidth => prevWidth + delta);
  };
```

Comment: Hello ! Do you have a complete example ? Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1):

Try this library - antd-table-ext.

Inside it uses react-resizable for resize.

Spoiler: I'm the creator of this library.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).